# How do I send transactions and transfer TT on ThunderCore mainnet?

Tags: javascript, web3js, thundercore

Without using ThunderCore Hub or any Web3 wallet which supports Thunder Token, how could I programmatically send transactions or transfer Thunder Tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a transaction on Thundercore, set these fields in the transaction:

- set `chainId` with from [`net_version()`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#net_version) ([`eth.net.getId()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-net.html#getid))
- set `nonce` with the value of [`eth_getTransactionCount()`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_gettransactioncount) ([`eth.getTransactionCount`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth.html#eth-gettransactioncount))
- set `gas price` from [`eth_gasPrice()`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_gasprice) ([`getGasPrice`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth.html#eth-gasprice))
- set `gas limit` from [`eth_estimateGas`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_estimategas) ([`eth.estimateGas`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth.html#estimategas))

See the `submitTx` method in the following code:

`transfer.js`

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const Accounts = require('web3-eth-accounts');
const Eth = require('web3-eth');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const BN = Web3.utils.BN;

const pretty = require('./pretty');
const erc20Abi = require('./ERC20.abi.json');

const web3Provider = () => {
  return Eth.giveProvider || 'https://mainnet-rpc.thundercore.com';
}

const signTx = async (fromAccount, tx) => {
  const signedTx = await fromAccount.signTransaction(tx)
  return signedTx.rawTransaction // hex string
}

class ChainHelper {
  constructor(eth, chainId, fromAccount) {
    this.eth = eth;
    this.chainId = chainId;
    this.fromAccount = fromAccount;
    this.fromAddress = fromAccount.address;
  }
  async submitTx(toAddress, value, txData) {
    const eth = this.eth;
    const promiseResults = await Promise.all([
      eth.getTransactionCount(this.fromAccount.address),
      eth.getGasPrice(),
    ]);
    const nonce = promiseResults[0];
    const gasPrice = promiseResults[1];
    const fromAddress = this.fromAddress;
    const tx = {
      'gasLimit': 0,
      'chainId': this.chainId,
      'gasPrice': gasPrice,
      'nonce': nonce,
      'from': fromAddress,
      'to': toAddress,
      'value': value,
      'data': txData,
    }
    const gasMultiple = new BN(1.0);
    tx.gasLimit = '0x' + (new BN(await eth.estimateGas(tx))).mul(gasMultiple).toString(16);
    console.log('tx:', pretty.format(tx));
    const rawTxStr = await signTx(this.fromAccount, tx);
    return eth.sendSignedTransaction(rawTxStr);
  }
  async transferToken (contractAddress, toAddress, value) {
    const eth = this.eth;
    const contractAbi = erc20Abi;
    const contract = new eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);
    const txData = contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, value).encodeABI();
    return this.submitTx(contractAddress, 0, txData);
  }
}

const create = async (privateKey) => {
  const accounts = new Accounts();
  if (!privateKey.startsWith('0x')) {
    privateKey = '0x' + privateKey;
  }
  const account = accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);
  const eth = new Eth(web3Provider());
  const networkId = await eth.net.getId();
  return new ChainHelper(eth, networkId, account);
}

const readKeys = () => {
  const privateKeys = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', '.private-keys'),
  {encoding: 'ascii'}).split('\n').filter(x => x.length > 0);
  return privateKeys;
}

module.exports = {
  create: create,
  readKeys: readKeys,
};
```

`testTransfer.js`

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const ChainHelper = require('../src/transfer.js');

const toAddress = '0x6f0d809e0fa6650460324f26df239bde6c004ecf';

describe('transfer', () => {
  it('transfer TT', async() => {
    const privateKey = ChainHelper.readKeys()[0]
    const c = await ChainHelper.create(privateKey);
    c.submitTx(toAddress, 1, '');
  });
  it('tokenTransfer', async() => {
    const privateKey = ChainHelper.readKeys()[0]
    const c = await ChainHelper.create(privateKey);
    /* Token.issue() */
    const jsonBuf = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'contracts', 'Token.json'));
    const contractData = JSON.parse(jsonBuf);
    const contractAbi = contractData['abi'];
    const contractAddress = contractData['networks'][c.chainId]['address'];
    const contract = new c.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);
    const toAddress = c.fromAddress;
    const tokenAmount = 2;
    let txData = contract.methods.issue(tokenAmount, c.fromAddress).encodeABI();
    let r = await c.submitTx(toAddress, 0, txData);
    console.log('Token.issue receipt:', r);
    /* Token.transfer() */
    r = await c.transferToken(contractAddress, toAddress, tokenAmount)
    console.log('Token.transfer receipt:', r);
  });
});
```

The code above targets the command line or server-side `node.js`, to send transactions from a browser replace `signTx` and `eth.sendSignedTransaction` with  [`web3.eth.sendTransaction`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth.html#eth-sendtransaction)

The complete example is in the [`transfer`](https://github.com/thundercore/field-support/tree/transfer) branch of this `field-support` repo.